# How to I increase the height of the panel plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi all I have a plot like the one in the figure, someone know how I can increase the height for example making white space that goes up to 60% so that I can put the image on the top of each bar? FOr example the Square image I would put it on the top of the bar
I am currently using the following code in R:

```
My_table = read.table("HEK293Piccoli_R.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
colnames(My_table) <- c("Status","Riboclique")
library(tidyverse)
x = factor(Species, level = c('Hexagon', 'Re', 'Square',"Tri5R","Tri","sRib"))
Ribo_plot <- ggplot(My_table, aes(factor(Riboclique, level = c('Hexagon', 'Re', 'Square',"Tri5R","Tri","sRib")),  group=Status)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop..),fill="seagreen4",alpha =.6, stat="count") +
  geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(..prop.., accuracy = .4),
                 y= ..prop.. ), stat= "count", vjust = -.3,size=7) +
  labs(y = "% Of Ribosome 
       in each conformation", fill="Riboclique") +
  labs(x="Riboclique", y="% Of Ribosome 
       in each conformation") +
  facet_grid(~Status) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+theme_bw(base_size = 30)
Ribo_plot

png("HEK293piccoli2", width = 800, height = 700)
plot(Ribo_plot)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 20), breaks = seq(0, 20, by = 1)` with `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0,0.6), breaks = seq(0,0.6, by = 0.1))`